Why am I getting “Too Many Requests” when I haven’t gone to SE in 12 hours?
For some reason, when I tried to access Stack Exchange today, it said “Too many requests”. That was only thing displayed. However, I hadn’t visited the site at all in 12 hours, and I have never run any script or anything that would make a large number of requests. This occurs everywhere on SE except for Chat. I tried clearing cookies, using another device, and restarting, with no effect. The only thing that did work (which is why I am able to post now) was using a VPN. Anyways, why is this happening? All the posts I found about it either has it going away much quicker than 12 hours, or being related to using an automated process to access SE

What do you mean? I wasn’t asking if you had this notice, but rather stating that I did…@user1176409

You mentioned you don't have any scripts running. Do you have any potentially oddball extensions running for your browser? Do you have anyone else on your network that was accessing SE?

@Spevacus no extensions that should do anything related to SE. No one else on my network that I know of accessed SE.

@testing-for-ya I don’t know. How would I find out?

@testing-for-ya seeing the Wikipedia contributions for my /21 and lower range there clearly other people, but is it by individual IP or range?

'dumb' question - is it a cloudflare error or a SE one?

The "Too Many Requests (from your IP)" response happens when SE thinks there are too many requests from your IP address with whatever time period SE is monitoring. The first level of your IP being put in this state normally results in about a 15 minute block on all requests to main or meta sites (chat is separately monitored, so isn't affected). Further "abusive" request levels result in longer bans. Bad configurations on SE's side have, in the past, resulted in the bans being permanent until SE is contacted to request a manual unblock. This behavior predates SE's change to Cloudflare.

@Makyen thank you. is there a way to request a manual unblock?

@Starship IIRC, the response includes what to do if you feel you shouldn't be getting that response. Did you read it? If it no longer contains that information, then I'd suggest the normal "Contact"/"Contact Us" that's at the bottom of every page.

The only text on the whole page is “Too Many Requests” @Makyen

It at least used to look like the screenshot in 'How long am I going to be rate-limited for "too many requests"?'

While we're generally not supposed to say "google it", you might be able to get more information from the questions in this Google search for "Too+Many+Requests"+site:meta.stackexchange.com

@Makyen I already performed that exact same search before asking this question :) See the last 2 sentences of the post

I contacted Stack Exchange using the Contact button on the bottom of every page. The issue was sent to the Trust and Safety team, and after some discussion, my IP was manually unblocked.
